# Add Play 2.0 to Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am following the instructions at http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/ to integrate `Play 2.0` into Intellij. But `Play` is not showing up in the repository thru Intellij. I typed `Browse Repository` and typed `Play` or `Play 2.0`. But nothing shows up.

EDIT: I search online. Some other people are having the same problem. But when they find the fix, they forget to share the solution.

Comment: Was your question answered or do you expect any other answer?

Answer (score 14):

Plug-in is available in the repository, try `Refresh` and make sure you are running compatible IDEA version ([12.0.3 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)).

[image: Play 2.0 Support]

Be aware that Play 2.0 Support plug-in is **available only for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate** Edition.

[Refer to this table](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) to see which features are not available in the Community Edition.

If you can't afford IDEA Ultimate, you still have 30 days to trial it or you can [apply for the open source license](http://www.jetbrains.com/eforms/openSourceRequest.action?licenseRequest=IIOSL).

Comment: my idea is `12.0.3`. I refresh, I restart. Nothing. And just like you I am in `Category: All` mode. I am using mac osx mountain lion.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, probably some proxy configuration or firewall/content filter, you can download the `.jar` and install it manually from the [plug-in page](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7080). Please note that this plug-in requires **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**, it will not work with the Community Edition.

Comment: I cannot afford `Ultimate`. Do you have any inkling as to what content filter may be affecting this?

Comment: Then it's the problem, if you can't afford Ultimate, you can't use this plug-in, sorry.

Comment: +1 for pointing out it's Ultimate edition only, that's what got me

Answer (score 3):

Play Plugin is not available in Intellij Community Edition.

You can use SublimeText2 or Eclipse to replace Intellij.

Comment: If you really want to add play to Intellij, please follow this tutorial http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE.